# ChatGPT gave me Qiskit code that used += to append a circuit?

Tags: qiskit, deutsch-jozsa-algorithm

I asked ChatGPT for a Qiskit implementation of Deutsch's algorithm.  I pasted the code it returned below.  Under where it says "# Apply the oracle gate", it tries to use "circuit += oracle".

Can "+=" actually be used in this fashion or some way similar?

````
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer, execute

# Define a function to create the Deutsch circuit
def deutsch_circuit(oracle):
    # Create a quantum circuit with two qubits and one classical bit
    circuit = QuantumCircuit(2, 1)

    # Initialize the input qubit to |0>
    circuit.x(1)

    # Apply a Hadamard gate to both qubits
    circuit.h(0)
    circuit.h(1)

    # Apply the oracle gate
    circuit += oracle

    # Apply another Hadamard gate to the first qubit
    circuit.h(0)

    # Measure the first qubit and store the result in the classical bit
    circuit.measure(0, 0)

    # Return the circuit
    return circuit

# Define the oracle for the constant function f(x) = 0
def constant_oracle():
    circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)

    # Do nothing

    # Return the oracle
    return circuit

# Define the oracle for the balanced function f(x) = x
def balanced_oracle():
    circuit = QuantumCircuit(2)

    # Apply a CNOT gate with the first qubit as control and the second qubit as target
    circuit.cx(0, 1)

    # Return the oracle
    return circuit

# Run the Deutsch algorithm with the constant function
circuit = deutsch_circuit(constant_oracle())
backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
result = execute(circuit, backend).result()
print(result.get_counts())

# Run the Deutsch algorithm with the balanced function
circuit = deutsch_circuit(balanced_oracle())
backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
result = execute(circuit, backend).result()
print(result.get_counts())
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator += used to be part of public interface of `QuantumCircuit`. It's deprecated in version 0.17 of Qiskit Terra with the recommendation to use [`compose()`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.compose.html) method instead which is more flexible w.r.t circuit register compatibility. And it's removed in version 0.23.